# Writing unit tests for search engine project

Tags: java, unit-testing

for a course I'm taking I'll be writing a pretty robust text search engine.

I was thinking of using test driven development to facilitate the development.

My problem is that I've never written unit tests before so I'm not sure what I should be testing for.

Would a test that for example runs a specific query expecting specific known results would be a good test (ie. run query "medicine", throw error if it does not return 5000 results) be a good candidate, or should my tests be smaller, testing smaller parts of the code instead of the whole program?

If that is the case what are some good examples of unit tests in a search engine application?

What are some good resources to get started at test driven development thinking ?

Comment: Just try it! that's a good idea. maybe JUnit to start?

Comment: This might be cheating, but: http://lucene.apache.org/core/